# When does idTokenChanges actually get invoked?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase_auth in my Flutter app. From the docs, I understand that idTokenChanges should get invoked automatically before the idToken of a FirebaseAuth instance gets expired. That should be at least one time in an hour. So I am trying to use that to refresh the idToken, which I later use to authenticate my web API calls. But after over an hour my listener does not get invoked and also I get 401 status for subsequent calls. So what is the proper place to use idTokenChanges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure you always use the updated token, just retrieve it before any call like so:

```
String token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.getIdToken();
```

That way, you ensure that you always have a valid token.

Other than that, you should listen to the `idTokenChanges` stream

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges().listen((user) => print(user.refreshToken));
```

But like you said, sometimes isn't reliable and may not trigger.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks. Are you aware of any way I can shorten the expiry time of the idToken at the backend, so that I can test the reliability (I need to have some proof before I can change existing code :) )

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible at all.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "It's sometimes not reliable"...? Really? Code is not like people, it's reliable! It's just a matter of finding out exactly how they work...

Comment: Not being reliable here may be related to having code from the SDK that could be buggy and not trigger sometimes. :)